# raspberry pi. listening for command from servers

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, raspberry-pi, network-monitoring

I have a raspberry pi that is attached to the same network as a few servers. Now I want to monitor these servers in a really basic way. I have written a program which does some checks on the server and I want to modify it to send a signal or command or whatever to the raspberry pi which then shows it on the monitor.

I have not much expertise in the area of networking but would such a thing be possible with FTP?

I know I can login to pi with ftp but I don`t know in what way I could 'listen' for certain commands that I send from my servers.

any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a file, on the raspberry, which will display something large on the screen, call the file /home/your_name/large, make it executable, then you can issue this command from the pc from which you ssh into the raspberry pi:

```
  ssh your_name@raspberrypi /home/your_name/large
```

This opens an ssh communication for the sole purpose of executing the command /home/your_name/large on the raspberry pi. If the command is made of two or more separate words, remember to use quotes to prevent the shell of the computer from which you are ssh'ing into the raspberry from interpreting it, instead of the raspberry:

```
 ssh your_name@raspberry 'cmd param1 param2 param3'
```

Answer (score 1):

`FTP` is not what you are looking for. There's a protocol specifically designed for monitoring, `SNMP`, but it can be quite complex to manage - although there are complete and easy installable suites for monitoring, i.e [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org).

If you just want to know if a server is alive you could send pings to the servers from the Raspberry and look at the result. On the other hand, if you want the server to communicate with the raspberry you should develop (or look for) some software that will get installed on the servers, open a socket and communicates with your Raspberry.

Comment: no it isn`t anything standard, I have a program which runs on the server which then would send some information to the pi and the pi displays it. what I want to display isn`t something standard like disk acces/ network I/O or something. I thought maybe sending just a certain line with the information would suffice it seems that is not possible, the information I am sending can be written in a single line.